# Why is [Char]-based input so much slower than the [Char]-based output in Haskell?

Tags: string, performance, haskell, io

It is a common knowledge that one does not use `[Char]` to read large amounts of data in Haskell. One uses `ByteString`s to do the job.
The usual explanation for this is that `Char`s are large and lists add their overhead.

However, this does not seem to cause any problems with the output.

For example the following program:

```
main = interact $ const $ unwords $ map show $ replicate 500000 38000000
```

takes just 131 ms to run on my computer, while the following one:

```
import Data.List

sum' :: [Int] -> Int
sum' = foldl' (+) 0

main = interact $ show . sum' . map read . words
```

takes 3.38 seconds if fed the output of the first program as an input!

What is the reason for such a disparity between the input and output performance using `String`s?

Comment: My quick profiling shows that the input program allocates 13 times more memory than the output program. This surely contributes to the disparity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that this issue necessarily has to do with I/O.  Rather, it demonstrates that the `Read` instance for `Int` is pretty inefficient.

First, consider the following program which just processes a lazy list.  It takes 4.1s on my machine (compiled with `-O2`):

```
main = print $ sum' $ map read $ words
        $ unwords $ map show $ replicate 500000 38000000
```

Replacing the `read` function with `length` drops the time down to 0.48s:

```
main = print $ sum' $ map length $ words
        $ unwords $ map show $ replicate 500000 38000000
```

Furthermore, replacing the `read` function with a handwritten version results in a time of 0.52s:

```
main = print $ sum' $ map myread $ words
        $ unwords $ map show $ replicate 500000 38000000

myread :: String -> Int
myread = loop 0
  where
    loop n [] = n
    loop n (d:ds) = let d' = fromEnum d  - fromEnum '0' :: Int
                        n' = 10 * n + d'
                    in loop n' ds
```

My guess as to why `read` is so inefficient is that its implementation uses the `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP` module, which may not be the fastest choice for the simple case of reading a single integer.

Comment: Oh, so the main reason not to use `String`s doesn't have anything to do with `String`s. This is so unfair.

Comment: To be fair, `read` does a few things that `myread` doesn't: error checking, whitespace skipping, negative numbers, hexadecimals, octals, and even (surprise!) exponential notation.

Comment: How does one write octals for `read`? I hope it's not prefix a number with `0`.

Comment: @Rotsor Octals for `read` are the same as octals in literal Haskell syntax: `0o32 = 26`.